# Using custom adapter for listview

Tags: android, listview, adapter

i'm very new to android and i'm trying to make a listview that will display details from a class I created

my activity is this:

```
public class UserList extends ListActivity {

private ListView lv;
private ArrayList<Player> players;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_list);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.UserListView);
    this.players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    this.players.add(new Player("AAAA"));
    this.players.add(new Player("BBBB"));
    PlayerAdapter pa = new PlayerAdapter(this, R.layout.userlist_list_item, this.players);
    lv.setAdapter(pa);
}
```

my adapter is this:

```
public class PlayerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Player> {

private ArrayList<Player> players;
private Context context;

public PlayerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Player> players) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, players);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.players = players;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.userlist_list_item, null);
    }
    Player p = players.get(position);
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListNameData);
    name.setText(p.getName());
    TextView money = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListMoneyData);
    money.setText(""+p.getCurrentmoney());
    TextView exp = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListExpData);
    exp.setText(""+p.getExp());

    return convertView;
}
```

the activity XML only has a listview and the list item XML is this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ListNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="@string/username" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ListNameData"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ListMoneyTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="@string/money" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ListMoneyData"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ListEXPTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="@string/expList" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ListExpData"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ListSwitchTo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/switchto" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ListDeleteUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/deleteuser" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my stack trace:

```
[2014-07-10 20:34:25 - ddms] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.launchInBackground(DebugUIPlugin.java:1286)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.launch(DebugUITools.java:753)
at      com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.debugRunningApp(AndroidLaunchController.java:178)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.clientChanged(AndroidLaunchController.java:1749)
at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.clientChanged(AndroidDebugBridge.java:926)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.update(Device.java:774)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.update(Client.java:903)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleWait.handleWAIT(HandleWait.java:88)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleWait.handleChunk(HandleWait.java:66)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.callHandler(MonitorThread.java:414)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:322)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

It crashes right away and I can't figure out how to fix it. 
Thank you for reading and hopefully helping me

Comment: Hey and welcome! As a little helping hand, when you experience a crash and want help on it, please, please, please post the stack trace, too. That, more than the code, is what really helps us diagnose your problem.

Comment: You don't need a class ref to players, that should be abstracted away though methods in ArrayAdapter. That's why it's passed in the super in the constructor. Use the built in methods like getItem(). I see this a lot with people who extend ArrayAdapter instead of BaseAdapter.

Comment: I'm not running the app on an emulator but on my phone, is there a way to get the stack trace that way?

Answer (score 0):

OK, your problem is in your adapter. The issue is with your `convertView`; you create a new View, `v`, which is what you expect that you will use. Instead, you use your `convertView` which is always null. This cause a `NPE` or `NullPointerException` to be thrown.

The simple solution is to just drop `v`. You really don't need to create a new name for a generic view; `convertView` will work just fine. Or you can just assign `v` to `convertView` once you inflate `v`.

Comment: I did it but nothing changed it still crashes

Comment: I've updated my original post with the latest adapter.

Comment: You are going to need to post the trace. I can't readily find the issue in what you have posted.

Comment: i've added the stack trace, hopefully you can find my problem now.

Comment: This exception has nothing to do with the adapter. Your debug library is throwing a null reference.

Comment: How can I fix it? and if this is not the problem than what is?

Comment: I don't know. Try running it without DDMS? If that doesn't work, I don't know what the problem is

Answer (score -1):

You can use baseadaper easy to work.  see this examples

[[http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/]](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/%5d)

Comment: This answer doesn't really address anything.